# How can I plot $y^x$?

Tags: graphing-functions, computer-algebra-systems, curves

How can I plot $y^x$? To keep things simple and to not have another $z$ variable on the other end of the equation, let's assume $y^x=10$. As long as that value is not $0$, the curve we get should look about the same.

The problem arises when $x$ is negative. The thing is, when $x$ is an odd, then y can only be a positive number. However, when $x$ is even, y can be either positive or negative. Therefore, if you look at the $x$ negative side of the graph, you would be able to mark a point whenever $x$ is even, but there would be no point when it is odd. So how could you graph such a thing? I simply have no idea what happens between two negative odd numbers (e.g. how does the curve behave between $-1$ and $-3$?)

As always, I tried WolframAlpha, and even it has trouble graphing the thing! [Here is what it ends up with](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%CB%86x%3D10%2C%20x%3D-100...100%2C%20y%3D-100...100).

Comment: Do you want to plot the real and imaginary parts then?

Comment: Well, I was thinking only about the real parts... Is there an imaginary part? When x is a negative even number, you would get a negative positive root. So, for example, when x = -2, then y = -√10.

Comment: Does it matter if I plot it in Matlab or must it be in Mathematica?

Comment: I don't know... I used Wolfram, and it goes crazy trying to solve it.

Comment: Do you want 2d plot?

Comment: My position: although expressions like $(-1)^3$ make sense, the function $y^x$ with real variable $x$ is considered to be defined only when $y\ge0$.

Comment: dustin - Yes, that's what I'm looking for. I would like to know if any sense can be made out of the negative part of x.

Rafflesia arnoldii - Yes, I think that may be the case. Have you seen the link I've posted? What do you think Wolfram could be trying to do in the negative x part? It draws a line, but it is all messed up. Maybe it's extrapolating a line from the points of even x?

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab:

```
>> x=linspace(-10,10,5000);
>> y=linspace(-10,10,5000);
>> t=y.^x-10;
>> plot(x,real(t))
>> plot(x,imag(t))
```

Real:

[image]

Imaginary:

[image]

---

Mathematica 3D plots:

```
Plot3D[Re[y^x - 10], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
Plot3D[Im[y^x - 10], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

Real:

[image]

Imaginary:

[image]

2D Contour plots:

```
ContourPlot[Re[y^x - 10], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
ContourPlot[Im[y^x - 10], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

Real:

[image]

Imaginary:

[image]

Comment: Wow! I can barely make any sense out of all this, I have to study many more years to get there... I can't understand, however, how, in the real 2D graph, y is increasing as x get's bigger. Shouldn't y equals the x-eth roots of 10?

Comment: @Rodrigo What you see as the y axis is really the z axis. You are looking at x vs z.

Answer (score 1):

$y^x = 10$ is equivalent to $e^{x\ln y}=10$, i.e. $\ln y=\frac{\ln 10}{x}$, or (again) $y=e^{\frac{\ln 10}{x}}$ (in particular, from the very beginning observe that we must have $y > 0$ for the expression to be defined without ambiguity). The latter form can be easily plotted, [e.g. via Mathematica.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20e%5E%28%28ln%2010%29%2Fx%29%2C%20x%3D-3..0)

Comment: Doesn't that just equal $\sqrt[x]{10}$? That can be obtained directly from the first equation, actually, by taking $x$-eth roots.

Comment: Indeed -- the main point of going to the definition of $y^x$ (which for $x$ real goes through the logarithm) is to highlight what the condition on $y$ is.